# Non-repeating-digit integers of a given length and of a given base.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, coding-theory

I am writing a program for a special purpose which needs non-repeating alphanumeric digit sequence of a given base and of a given length.
For example, if the given base is 28 so digits are 0-9A-R, and the sequence length given is 11 so the first non-repeating-digit sequence is 0123456789A. 
I have coded 2 {not so intelligent i guess} algorithms in python and c, they works but will need several months to complete the calculations and i have no access to any high performance scientific computing rig. First method is by repeatedly incrementing long long unsigned int base 10 variable and calculating the base 28 then filtering out the any resulting base 28 number with repeated digits. Another method is using addition in base 28, repeatedly adding 1 and then filtering out the any resulting base 28 number with repeated digits.

Are there special existing ways/algorithms in math to do it? Or peoples have already completed it and have a list of non-repeating-digit integers?

What is the mathematical way to get all the non-repeating-digit Integers of given length and a given base?

And please understand that I am not a math student, so please write back in a way that I can understand.

Regards.

Comment: Do you only want to count the numbers (which is just $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$, when $n$ is the base and $k$ the length) or to generate all the numbers ?

Comment: I want to generate all the numbers.btw what is the meaning of the exclamation marks in the equation you given!

Comment: It is the factorial : $n!=1\cdot 2\cdots\cdot n$. Note that $0!=1$

Comment: Sorry, I currently don't know about it. But how can I generate the numbers?

Comment: You can use nested for-loops, if the length is fixed. I do not know an efficient program code in Python or c without an explicitely known length.The example with base $28$ and length $11$ however has too many possible words to generate them all within a reasonable time.

Comment: I am already using loops to get it. But my problem is it's inefficient and taking to much long time even in pure c.

Comment: If the problem is to avoid duplicate letters efficiently, I am sorry, I do not know an algorithm. I guess currently you let every digit run and then compare the digits if a duplicate occurs, right ?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: BTW, I appreciate you replied to my question. Thanks. @Peter

Comment: Cross-posted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/300107

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want all combinations of $n$ objects (the digits) taken $t$ at a time. If you are working in Python, the combinations() function in the itertools module will do this for you.

Comment: @awkward thanks for replying. I want a way to generate all the unsigned integers possible with some special properties and scope. 1) the Integers must be 11 digits long. 2) the Integers must be of a certain base, e.g base 28. 3) this is the most important property that any digits must not repeat in a generated integer. examples, 0123456789A, DF345B6789A, DF805B678CH etc. etc. There are no time related factors here in my mind but as I said I am not a math guy so you may be correct but maybe I am not understanding it. Maybe. I just want to say, please help me out with this math problem.

Comment: @awkward Sorry I mistakenly wrote DF805B678CH where it have repeated digit 8. But you got the idea i guess.